# How to pass data from one path to another in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I have a list of locations that I send as a JSON to one path:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    List<GeoLoc> list = new ArrayList<GeoLoc>();
    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/myjson/{arraySize}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<GeoLoc> createJSON(@PathVariable("arraySize") int arraySize)
```

So on the path localhost:8080/myjson/somenumber I will have a list of JSONs.

But then, I would like to get that data from other method and path so that instead of JSON structure like this: {ID:1, town: "New York"} I got something like 1, New York. Basically plain String with comas, but I want that to be under other path, for example /myStrings. How could I make that request to read data from one path, change it and put into the another path? The @GetMapping changes my localhost:8080/myjson instead of just reading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the other method belongs to the same controller, you can just call locally the 'createJSON()' method and apply the transformations you need.

In case the other method belongs to a different controller, I think you could @Autowire the respective controller.

Comment: Hi! Yes I could do that, but as a task for University I need to know how to pass the value from one path to another. Unfortunatelly when I try to do that with GET i modify the original path.